# Plotting elements of a sequence on number line

Tags: plot, tikz-pic

i plotted the number line which includes (0,1) interval

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \begin{axis}[
            axis x line=middle,
            axis y line=none,
            height=50pt,
            width=\axisdefaultwidth,
            xmin=0,
            xmax=1, ]
     \addplot coordinates {
                (1,0) (0.5,0) (0.3,0) (0.25,0) (0.625,0)
                }; 
      \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

So far i putted 5 dots on line but i want to put all elements of the sequence

`$ \{ a_n \}=\frac{1}{n}$` which has infinitely many elements.

secondly i used xtick={0,0.125,0.250.5,1} and it was not give any good result, it corrupt the number line :)

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your sequence is a normal function, so you could plot the function `1/x`.

Comment: it is not a function it is squence so, the elements of a squence must represented by points @TeXnician

Comment: as n  is natural number which starts from 1,2,3,...  graph must include the points that  (1, 1\2, 1\3, 1\4, 1\5, .... ) @TeXnician

Comment: A sequence is a function whose domain is a subset of the integers: see [here](http://www.corestandards.org/Math/Content/HSF/IF/) for example.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
  ymin = 0,
  ymax = 1,
  xmin = 0,
  xmax = 100,
  axis x line=center,
  axis y line=left]
    \addplot[samples at={1,...,100},only marks,mark size=0.2]{1/x};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Excactly what I suggested and the OP rejected ;)

Comment: thanks , it was excatly what i want to do @TeXnician :P but  i need the projection  of the points onto y axis  so it can be represented with (0,1) line which covered by number line

Comment: @TeXnician Maybe the misunderstanding was about "plotting a normal function". If one identifies normal or plotting with continuous, then this is not what the OP wanted.

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you want then, or am I just confused as usual?

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
            axis x line=middle,
            axis y line=none,
            height=50pt,
            width=\axisdefaultwidth,
            xmin=0,
            xmax=1, ]
     \addplot[samples at={1,...,100},only marks,mark size=1,blue] (1/x,0);
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}  
\end{document}
```

Comment: thanks @Torbjørn T.  , you understand what i want better than me :)